# How to make a list-search program in python using only recursion?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a python program (**using only recursion, no looping**) which takes a list of names from user and also a name to search for the list. The program has to tell whether the name exists in the given list or not. Additionally, if an element of the list is `"James Christ"` and we search for `"James"`, the program should return true. 
I have made half of the program. But my code doesn't perform the additional function.
My code is like this:

```
L1=list(input("Enter the list of names : "))
x=input("Enter the name to search : ")

def search(L1,x):
    if len(L1)==0:
        return "Not found!!"
    else:
        if x==L1.pop(0):
         return "Entry found!!"
        else:
         return search(L1,x)

print search(L1,x)
```

Please, help me out!

Comment: You know that the list will change when you use `pop`?

Comment: @Matthias: That's the idea, otherwise the recursion wouldn't work.

Comment: It would. See my answer.

Comment: @Matthias: Fair enough, passing a slice also works and is nice if you must keep the list. On the other hand, it creates many copies of the list, requiring lots of memory (n^2, not great for long lists).

Comment: It's all academic. Nobody would use recursion for this task in a real world program.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution without destroying the original list.

```
montys = [
    'John Cleese', 'Graham Chapman', 'Terry Gilliam',
    'Eric Idle', 'Terry Jones', 'Michael Palin']
actor = 'Idle'


def search(data, word):
    if len(data) == 0:
        return "Not found!"
    else:
        if word in data[0]:
            return "Entry found!"
        else:
            return search(data[1:], word)

print(search(montys, actor))
```

For more information see Junuxx answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if x==L1.pop(0)`, use `if x in L1.pop(0)`.

This will work for `James` and `James Christ`, but also for `Jamesy Bob` or `SuperJames`.

To make sure that the input matches an entire word of the name in the list, you could do `if x in L1.pop(0).split()`. This works by splitting `James Christ` into a list of words (`['James', 'Christ']`) and checking if 'James' occurs as one of the words in that list.

Comment: @M_G: You're welcome! :) Feel free to upvote good answers or to accept a best answer, so that others can easily see that the problem is resolved.

Comment: I am so much happy that I could upvote your answer 10 times myself. I can't do even once b'coz my reputation is below the minimum required to upvote. :( . Sorry,man!!

Comment: Let me add: the answer with the textual information concerning the main problem is this one. My answer addresses the problem of the disappearing list.